# Any alternatives of solve() which is slow

Tags: r, performance

A represents how much each industry of country is related to other industry of other country. It could takes values from around 1.00. So diagonal element of matrix A is close to 1 but the off diagonal element of matrix A is much smaller than 1 since each industry is mostly related to itself.

I,J stands for countries which are 1:44 each, 
Caution! ("I" in solve(I-A_omit(J,j)) is a diag(2464).
i,j stands for industries which are 1:56 each.

X is the output which is a vector of length 44 countries X 56 industries = 2464 
It is calculated by the inverse of (diag(2464)-A) multiplied by F(a matrix which is a 2464 * 1 matrix representing final demand of a industry in a specific country.)

X_omit(J,j) is a function which changes all the values in industry j of country J into zero.
 In here, the j+56*(J-1)th column of matrix X is turned into zero.
By the way, "I" in solve(I-A_omit(J,j)) is a diag(2464).

One calculation of `X_omit`(using `solve`) takes about 20 seconds. 
`A` is an 2464*2464 matrix and `X` is an 2464*1 matrix. 
I assume calculating `b_link` takes about 20 seconds * 2464 calculation which is 14 hours for just one single value.
But in this case, I have managed to change it to a simple equation using `sum` because in this case, separating `I` and `i` doesn't matter.
But in next calculation I am about to do, `I`,`i`,`J`,`j` which is dimension `1:44,1:56,1:44,1:56` and each letters should be separated, not just using sum.

I think the only way to make it faster is by making `solve()` which takes 20 seconds faster. [A] matrix in `solve(I-A_omit(J,j))` is not symmetric, just normal matrix filled with numbers.

This is my code

```
X_omit <- function (J,j) {solve((I-A_omit(J,j)),F)}
B_linkages_inter <- function (I,J) {
  for (j in 1:56) {
    for (i in 1:56) {
      sum((X[i+56*(I-1)]-X_omit(J,j)[i+56*(I-1)])/X[j+56*(J-1)])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you add the code to your question please, instead of an image. thanks ps. [ it would be great if you added a small example, with expected result for people to work with: then focus can move to scaling it up to the problem  dimension ]

Comment: Thanks for updating, but please try to add an example, on a much smaller scale , to show what you are trying to do please : maybe append it to the bottom of your question.

Comment: You can use `solve(A,b)` instead of `solve(A)%*%b`. That will be faster because it doesn't actually invert the matrix. If it's still slow you can try using the Revolution R open distribution of R.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will try both as soon as i finish my current calculation and tell you which one was faster.

Comment: "X_omit(J,j) is a function which changes all the values in industry j of country J into zero." - no it isn't. "A function which changes all the values in industry j of country J into zero" does not need to call solve.

Comment: Besides, you did not specify what is `A_omit`, and it is not present in your code.

Comment: Finally, your function `b_link` does not print or return anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate `X_omit(J,j)` outside the loops. Besides, you can also calculate `X[j+56*(J-1)])` outside the loops.

Comment: I have changed the code to inter-country backward linkage, in which nothing(in my opinion) could come outside the loop. A_omit <- function (J,j) {A[,j+56*(J-1)]<-0; A}. A is just a 2464*2464 matrix.

Comment: why did you change the code in a such way that nothing could come outside it?

Comment: The previous one was backward linkage within country. Now, it is backward linkage between countries which is also a data I need to know.